# Equivalent theories of general relativity and graviton spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-spin

Are there equivalent theories of general relativity that assume a graviton has a spin-1?

Answer (score 2):

Since GR predicts that the graviton has spin-2 (or, more precisely, that gravitational waves have two helicity-2 polarizations), then *by definition* any theory that predicts that a graviton has spin-1 must be different from GR.